# Does there exist a function $f$ from $R^2$ to $R$ and constant $c_0>0$ such that for all $x,y\in R^2$, $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge c_0|x-y|^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I know the function must be injective as for $x \not= y$, $c_0|x-y|^2>0$.  Thus the function cannot be continuous.  I'm feeling that no such function exists but I'm not sure how I would justify this.

Comment: Assuming $c_0=1$, let us restrict our function to the set $\Gamma_d=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|(u,v)\|=d\}$ and study the diameter $\Phi_d$ of $f(\Gamma_d)$. Antipodal points give $\Phi_d\geq 4d^2$ and equilateral triangles in $\Gamma_d$ give $\Phi_d\geq 6d^2$. If we consider the Petersen graph [as a unit distance graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph) we get a stronger lower bound. If there were unit distance graphs with arbitrarily high chromatic number our job would be done ($\Phi_d=+\infty$).

Comment: Unluckily the chromatic number of a unit distance graph is at most seven, hence this approach cannot give something stronger than $\Phi_d\geq (24-\varepsilon)d^2$. On the other hand, this approach might be salvageable through some suitable tensor trick or some inequality of the $\Phi_{d/2}\geq 1+ \Phi_d$ kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [*this answer*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392024/lipschitz-space-filling-maps), it is proved that the [*Hilbert space-filling curve*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) is Hölder continuous with exponent $\frac{1}{2}$. Althouth the original curve is a mapping $[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$, it is easy to extend this function to a surjection $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which is also Hölder continuous: there exists $C > 0$ such that

$$ \| g(t) - g(s) \| \leq C |t - s|^{1/2}. $$

Since $g$ is a surjective, we can find an injective function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g\circ f = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}^2} $. Then this function satisfies

$$ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \quad \| x - y \|^2 \leq C^2 |f(x) - f(y)|. $$

So the condition is satisfied with $c_0 = C^{-2} > 0$.

Comment: (+1) Ahh, I was going in the wrong direction. But this leads to an interesting follow-up question: given your $f$, what is the behaviour of the diameter of $f(\{(u,v):u^2+v^2=r^2\})$?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  Can you explain a bit more as to how to extend the function while maintaining the H\"older continuity?

Comment: @Sarah, It is actually straightforward. Since the Hilbert curve is an exotic way of parametrizing the unit square with two marked corners (which are endpoints of the curve), it is enough to prepare a countably many copies of unit squares and concatenate them along with those endpoints to tile the plane.